# Beginner prime factorization

Tags: python, primes, factors

I wrote a beginner program that aims to find and print the prime factors of any number:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 3:
        return True
    elif n == 4:
        return False
    else:
        n = int(n**0.5)+1
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True

def prime_factors(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            x = i
            primes.append(x)
            y = n / x
            return y
            break


primes = []

def main(y):
    while not is_prime(y):
        y = prime_factors(y)
    primes.append(y)
    print(primes)
```

Here are examples of runs of the program, which have me confused:

```
main(625)

[5, 5, 5, 5]

...

main(160)

[160]

...

main(6)

[6]

...

main(1007)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Some inputs work, and some don't. I can't figure out why. I also can't figure out how to fix that error from coming up. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: *Your code* has me confused. Why doesn't `prime_factors` check if each factor `is_prime`? Why do you have one fixed list of `primes`? I don't see why you'd expect this to work at all.

Comment: however specifically ... if `n%i `is never equal to zero then it returns None which gets assigned to y. `is_prime(None)` tries to get the square root but fails because `None**0.5 == ?` for example  `prime_factors(5)` would return None

Comment: what is the `break` doing immediately after a `return`?

Comment: @Joel Illuminating my stupidity. Didn't know `return` breaks. _But_, this is my first program. So I don't feel too bad about it.

Comment: Just to explain what the problem is: in the `n=int(n**0.5)+1` statement, you changed the value of `n`.  But two lines later you check if `n%i==0`.  You want it to be the old `n`.  So at least you need to use `m=int(n**5)+1`, but even better would be to give it a more descriptive name.  Characters are cheap these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `is_prime` function seems to incorrectly reuse the variable `n` in these lines:

```
    n = int(n**0.5)+1
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
```

You might consider using more descriptive names, such as `factor_limit` for example.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me here. There is a bug here even if `n` is not `None`.

Comment: With all respect guys, why even bother to check if the divisors are primes? checking if a number is prime takes time and a lot of iterations, it may be faster just to divide for all numbers < n over and over.
Don't say "oohh you will finding useless non-prime divisors" because if you do it in order, you will find 2 before 4 hehe

Comment: @MartinE.Zulliger: There are certainly better ways to write the overall algorithm. However, this sort of brute force method will still work, after the bugs are removed.

Comment: Wow. After I simply removed `n = int(n**0.5)+1` every single run has worked perfectly and I'm pretty sure it fixed the whole program. Works great now. I saw that used in another prime factoring program and realized that you only have to check up to the square root of a number, but implementing it actually hurt my own program. I understand the idea can still be used but I'm just gonna roll with what I have for now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you have many many problems , here are some of the most noticeable ones

**1.**
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'float'`

is telling you that python doesnt know how to `None**0.5`

**2.** as mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30040648/541038) you are checking if the square root of n is divisble by i not if N is divisible by i

**3.**

```
def prime_factors(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            x = i
            primes.append(x)
            y = n / x
            return y
            break #<--- this is totally worthless and does nothing
    #if you get here you are returning None... which breaks(see #1)
    return [1] #might fix your problem ...
```

there are likely some other issues as well

Comment: Thank you. Fixed the `NoneType` issue by removing the whole idea of only checking up to square root (`n = int(n**0.5)+1`), and it works now but I could still correctly reimplement that. Also, yeah, did not know returning breaks, even though it should be common sense. Beginner probs.